# How to properly use semicolon for a list of sentences in business writing?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, punctuation, lists, semicolons

I ran into a fraud company and now trying to file a dispute. But unfortunately, it didn't approve. So, right now I'm trying to fight it by starting with the refund policy. And hoping someone can help me see if they have any grammar and punctuation errors. And wondering if this is the correct way to write in business writing.

In the refund policy they were using ; to start the list and ended each sentence with a period. But I remember in school we can only separate a list of sentences with ; or .

They wrote

```
...Refund Policy will be Void if; 
You have chosen a special or a custom package.
```

If it ended with a period isn't that mean the next sentence is no longer part of the refund policy?

[image]

Comment: Set off the list with a colon, not a semicolon. It seems standard practice to terminate each item of a "displayed list" with a full stop, but an "in-line list," so to speak, with commas, semicolons if it improves clarity. In my book you're dealing with a typo.

Comment: The entire page of text is badly punctuated. Replacing the semicolon after "will be Void if" in the first line with a colon only begins to remedy the faults of the presentation. It would be wise to indent the next 13 sentences and precede each sentence with a bullet point. That would signal to the reader that the sentence beginning with "Reasons such as 'change of mind', ..." isn't simply the 14th possible grounds for voiding the refund policy, but rather the start of a different topic (namely, other bases for denying a refund that don't amount to voiding the company's refund  policy).

Comment: Punctuation has a long, torrid history in law that has changed over time. You'd get a much more relevant answer on law.stackexchange.com.